# Is this casting away const?

Tags: c++, casting

```
const char cp[]="jkasdkasjsad";
string a=static_cast<string>(cp);//"const string a" also runs without any error
```

I have stuck at the above code for the whole afternoon. C++ Primer only give a code like

```
const char cp[]="jkasdkasjsad";
static_cast<string>(cp);
```

Could someone tell me is my code legal? Could I call it "cast away const" since no "const" before "string a"?

> Any well-defined type conversion, other than those involving low-level const, can be
>   requested using a `static_cast`. For example, we can force our expression to use
>   floating-point division by casting one of the operands to double:

I was confused about the description above, what does "those involing low-level const" mean? Involving at left side or right side of an assignment? 
Anyone can save me.. Many thanks!

Comment: This is no different from `const int j = 3; int q = (int) j;`. No casting away of const here.

Comment: Yeah it's just a copy initilization. Maybe I should stop reading this book for a while... Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not legal. There is no definition of `string`. Do you want people to guess what it is, and give you advice based on those guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string from `cp` array is being copied, string variable is not const

```
const char cp[] = "jkasdkasjsad";
std::string a = static_cast<std::string>(cp);
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::string ab = cp;
```

`cp` decays to pointer to first element of `cp` array

Comment: but we can't modify the char array through the string variable right? Since the char is const itself

Comment: no - we cannot, but the reason is that string has its own copy of this char array.

Comment: Concise and clear. So I accept your answer. Thanks for the efforts!

Answer (score 2):

There is no real casting at all in this case.

```
static_cast<string>(cp);
```

is equivalent to call to string constructor

```
string(cp);
```

Temporary variable of type `string` constructed from `cp` will be returned from `static_cast`. Since, I think we talk about [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), than this constructor will be called

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the
>   null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the
>   string is determined by the first null character.

Comment: but is that string variable const? because it was casted from a const char array

Comment: No the string variable doesn't need to be const - because it contains a *copy* of your const char array.  If you wrote `char *p = const_cast<char*>(cp);` that would be "casting away const".  You now have a pointer to non-const char that is pointing into your cp array.  Technically, this code is legal.  What is not legal, is to then write `*p = 'b';`.  Basically though, you don't want to use const_cast at this point in learning C++

Comment: Ok I have to leave for a while. I will come back in 10 mins!!

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for the efforts but I feel I can understand his answer better. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly legal according to the clause 5.2.9/4 of C++ standard:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a
>   `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);`
>   is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5). The
>   effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the
>   declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable
>   as the result of the conversion.

For your example `T` is `std::string`, `e` is `cp`. There is no casting away constness because of new object creation. Compare with this:

```
char* p = static_cast<char*>(cp); // error
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts!